# Cmake error when compiling ros_tutorials packages in windows 10 ROS 2 Foxy Fitzroy Patch Release 4

Tags: ros2, colcon, qt5, windows10, begginer-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just followed the instructions in [Installing ROS 2 on Windows](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Windows-Install-Binary/). After that, I tried to create a workspace following [this tutorial](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace/#build-the-workspace-with-colcon) but at step 5, I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\dev_ws>colcon build --merge-install
Starting >>> turtlesim
--- stderr: turtlesim
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package):
By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
the following names:

Qt5Config.cmake
qt5-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
to a directory containing one of the above files. If "Qt5" provides a
separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

Failed <<< turtlesim [1.20s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [1.39s]
1 package failed: turtlesim
1 package had stderr output: turtlesim
```

It's weird because on the installing tutorial(binaries) doesn't say anything about extending the variable "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH" to include the Qt5 directory. Not even in the "Building ROS 2 on Windows" tutorial. I found some Qt folders in the share folder of the zip installation. I'm guessing I don't need to install Qt because the installation already comes with it. Moreover, "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH" already points to the installation directory: "C:\dev\ros2_foxy" where those Qt folders are.

This is the system I'm using:

> Operating System: Windows 10
>
> Installation type: binaries
>
> Version or commit hash: ROS 2 Foxy
> Fitzroy Patch Release 4

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370180/cmake-error-when-compiling-ros_tutorials-packages-in-windows-10-ros-2-foxy-fitzroy-patch-release-4/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2021-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that in order to fix it I needed to install the Qt win64_msvc2019_64 in C:\Qt. Then, set the variable:

> set Qt5_DIR=C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64

or set it permanently:

> setx -m Qt5_DIR
> C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64

Basically, follow the [Building ROS 2 on Windows](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Windows-Development-Setup/#install-qt5) but only the "Install Qt5" section because there is no Qt win64_msvc2019_64 in `C:\dev\ros2_foxy`

---

Originally posted by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) with karma: 188 on 2021-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0